How should I set the `scale` argument in the `reduceRegion` function if I applied a buffer around the points?
I am using the script below to calculate and export EVI2 values derived from Sentinel-2 data to a table. Since the 10-meter spatial resolution of Sentinel-2 is insufficient to represent the area I need, I applied a 30-meter buffer to my points to include information from the surrounding area.
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-marciobcure/assets/coordenadas_dexter_2025").limit(5);

var geometry = table
  .limit(5)
  .geometry()
  .buffer({'distance': 30});
  
// Sentinel 2
var idCollection = 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED';

//Definição da ImageCollection e Filtros Geoespaciais
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

var col = ee.ImageCollection(idCollection)
        .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2024-01-31')//filtro de intervalo de período
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))//filtro de nuvens
        .map(maskS2clouds)
        .select(['B8', 'B4']); //B2, B3, B4, B8, B11

col = col.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry));

//Map.addLayer(col);
//print("col", col);
print(col.size());

var table_list = table.toList(table.size());

var newCol = table_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var new_col = col.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(ee.Feature(ele).geometry()));
  
  var getData = new_col.toList(new_col.size()).map(function (e) {
    
    var date = ee.Date(ee.Image(e).get("system:time_start")).format().slice(0,10);
    
    var evi2 = ee.Image(e).expression(
    '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+(2.4*RED)+1)', {
      'NIR': ee.Image(e).select('B8').divide(10000),
      'RED': ee.Image(e).select('B4').divide(10000)
    }).rename('EVI2');
    
    
    var value = ee.Image(evi2).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: ee.Feature(ele).geometry(),
      scale: 30
    }).get('EVI2');
    
    var ft = ee.Feature(null, {'date': date, 
                               'value': value,
                               'plot_id': ee.Feature(ele).get('plot_id'),
    });
    
    return ft;
    
  });
  
  return getData;
  
});

print(newCol.size());

// // Export the time-series as a csv.
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(newCol.flatten()),
    selectors: 'date, value, plot_id',
    description: 's2_Dexter_2025',
    folder: 'Dexter2025_csv'
});

I have three questions:

Is this approach adequate to achieve my objective?
How should I set the scale argument in the reduceRegion function? Did I use it properly?
Why did I get the error Collection.toList: The value of 'count' must be positive. Got: 0 when running my script in Google Earth Engine? (SOLVED: I applied .limit(5) to table and edited the code above.)

I kept the number of points to 5 to save time, effort, and storage.

Please provide the code directly in the question.
